# How can I use a macro argument as a pst-node label?

Tags: pstricks, pst-node

In the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node}

\begin{document}

\def\working(#1,#2,#3, #4){
    \rput(#1,#2){
        \ovalnode{M5}{
            #4
        }
    }
}


\def\notworking(#1,#2,#3,#4){
    \rput(#1,#2){
        \ovalnode{M#3}{
            #4
        }
    }
}

\psset{unit=1cm}

\begin{pspicture}
\working(1,1, 5, WORKING)
\ovalnode{Start}{Start}
\ncarc{Start}{M5}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}
\notworking(1,1, 5, NOTWORKING)
\ovalnode{Start}{Start}
\ncarc{Start}{M5}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

there are two very similar macros. In the "working" macro, the node label "M5" is hard-coded. The first picture indeed creates the "M5" node and connects it to the "Start" node:

[image]

But, I want the node-label to be a macro argument. This is not working, as shown in the "notworking" macro. I see "NOTWORKING" and "Start" but they are not connected:

[image]

How can I make it work?

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'? Your code compiles without errors for me and the output looks the same for both nodes. (Although compiling with `auto-pst-pdf` seems to chop off the left edge of each node. Compiling with `xelatex` or `latex+dvips` and without `auto-pst-pdf` solves that issue though.)

Comment: @AlanMunn I added an explanation. It was created with xelatex and without auto-pst-pdf.

Comment: Thanks for the update. This makes the problem clearer, but I suspect you have an outdated version of something, since this compiles correctly on my system (TL 2015).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this definition you expect a space before the fourth parameter:

```
\def\working(#1,#2,#3, #4){
        \rput(#1,#2){
            \ovalnode{M5}{
                #4
            }
        }
    }
```

`\working(1,1,5, WORKING)` will be ok, but `\working(1,1,5,WORKING)`is not; the space before "WORKING" is missing. However use

```
\def\working(#1,#2,#3,#4){%  NO SPACE HERE
        \rput(#1,#2){%
            \ovalnode{M5}{%
                #4%
            }%
        }%
    }
```

The `%` are not all really needed, because PSTricks kills trailing spaces if you are inside a PSTricks object. If not you get a lot of these spaces.

Comment: OK... Now I see. So it is not related to pstricks it all. Only a matter of spaces before the macro parameters.

Answer (score 1):

This works flawlessly:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node}

\begin{document}

\def\working(#1,#2,#3,#4){%
    \rput(#1,#2){%
        \ovalnode{M5}{%
            #4%
        }%
    }%
}


\def\notworking(#1,#2,#3,#4){%
    \rput(#1,#2){%
        \ovalnode{M#3}{%
            #4%
        }%
    }%
}

\psset{unit=1cm}

\begin{pspicture}
\working(1,1,5,WORKING)
\ovalnode{Start}{Start}
\ncarc{Start}{M5}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}
\notworking(1,1,5,WORKING)
\ovalnode{Start}{Start}
\ncarc{Start}{M5}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

and gives the same result for both pictures.

[image]

Comment: It works! But I do not understand why?